# MySQL: Why is my index length 0.0 bytes?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, relational

I have a simple table containing 4 columns.

Column A (int), Column B (int), Column C (int), Column D (int)

I have constructed an index on (Column B, Column A, Column C), which works well performance wise. My table contains 5 million rows, and using the index to select desired rows works instantly (<0.00 s).

While inspecting the table, however, I see that my Index length is 0.0 bytes. Why? How can my index take no memory at all?

Info:

> SHOW CREATE TABLE kpi_store_hour

CREATE TABLE `kpi_store_hour` (   `kpiID` int(11) NOT NULL,   `companyID` int(11) NOT NULL,   `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,   `value` float NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`kpiID`,`companyID`,`timestamp`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

> SHOW TABLE STATUS

Name: kpi_store_hour

Engine: InnoDB

Version: 10

Row_format: Compact

Rows: 4973952

Avg_row_length: 95

Data_length: 476037120

Max_data_length: 0

Index_length: 0

Data_free: 6291456

Auto_increment: NULL

Create_time: 2015-03-04 11:14:06

Update_time: NULL

Check_time: NULL

Collation: utf8_general_ci

Checksum: NULL

> SELECT * FROM kpi.kpi_store_hour WHERE kpiID = 0 AND companyID = 1 AND timestamp < 1353792707;

Duration/fetch: 0.000 sec / 0.000 sec

> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM kpi.kpi_store_hour WHERE kpiID = 0 AND companyID = 1 AND timestamp < 1353792707;

id: 1

select_type: SIMPLE

table: kpi_store_hour

type: range

possible_keys: PRIMARY

key: PRIMARY

key_len: 12

ref: NULL

rows: 743

Extra: Using where

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SHOW TABLE STATUS`, the `SELECT`, and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  There are _many_ possible explanations; those bits of info should make it easy to give you an answer.

Comment: Thank you, I have added that info to the OP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In InnoDB, the `PRIMARY KEY` is "clustered" with the data.  Phrased differently, the data is stored in a BTree that is ordered by the PK.  Since the two (data and PK) co-exist, their size is counted in `Data_length` (476MB) and nothing in `Index_length`.  If you had any 'secondary' keys, they would be counted in `Index_length`.

The table has 4 4-byte fields, so theoretically a row should occupy only 16 bytes.  Note that `Avg_row_length` is 95.  This is because of

- Overhead for each column
- Overhead for each row
- Overhead for BTree
- and some overhead for the PRIMARY KEY.

`key_len: 12` -- That implies that the 3 4-byte fields in the PK were used...

`WHERE kpiID = 0 AND companyID = 1 AND timestamp < 1353792707` could quickly drill down in the BTree to the first row with `kpiID = 0 AND companyID = 1`, then scan until `timestamp < 1353792707` fails.  And it estimated that 743 rows would be encountered.

Comment: I understand. The reason as to why I was trying to determine the Index length was to get an idea of how much the index would grow in size along with my table. Thank you very much for the answer!